# Hibernate: Build a list of Unique Strings - not entities

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, unique, distinct

I am storing and retrieving Java Entities in a DB using Hibernate.

I need to build up (for the purposes of creating web-page 'drop-downs' / 'lookups') a list of unique strings.

NB: I don't really want to retrieve back Entities here as such - I want to run the equivalent of a SQL 'SELECT DISCTINCT(column) FROM table;' and get back a list of strings.

Is there a standard Hibernate Idiom for doing this - or should I use another mechanism ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hibernate query is supporting that query, you can use either hql or native query to get String.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select distinct user.firstname from User as user");
```

or

```
Query query = session.createNativeQuery("select distinct user.firstname from User user");

List<String> list = (List<String>) query.list();
```

Reference: [Hibernate Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)